# How To create fixed size mutable stack allocated string in rust?

Tags: string, memory-management, rust, utf-8, char

Suppose I know the size of a variable which should be **stack allocated** and be of **string type** and **mutable** then how can i create a string type variable that is mutable but of fixed size and hence stack memory is allocated

Using **String** would give me heap allocated dynamic length variable

Using **str**  would mean i should give the value in compile time itself

Using **array of bytes** would do it but i will lose functionality associated with string type

Comment: Similar to the [arrayvec](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec) crate, there is an [arraystring](https://crates.io/crates/arraystring) crate that seems to do what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to make a `&mut str` from `&mut [u8]` with [`std::str::from_utf8_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/fn.from_utf8_mut.html). Example:

```
fn main() {
    // Just an example of creating byte array with valid UTF-8 contents
    let mut bytes = ['a' as u8; 2];
    // Type annotation is not necessary, added for clarity
    let string: &mut str = std::str::from_utf8_mut(&mut bytes).unwrap();
    // Now we can call methods on `string` which require `&mut str`
    string[0..1].make_ascii_uppercase();
    // ...and the result is observable
    println!("{}", string); // prints "Aa"
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cf92069dd6ab8f84ef3bb5f6291e10bb)